# Why is "sudo virsh" hanging in the console?

Tags: virtualization, openstack

I wanted to experiment with OpenStack on my iMac:
So I installed [Ubuntu Cloud Live Image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure) on a VM and I also ran DevStack on a fresh Ubuntu 64-bit Server VM.

The [DevStack script](http://devstack.org/stack.sh.html) hangs on the following line:

```
instances=`sudo virsh list --all | grep $INSTANCE_NAME_PREFIX | sed "s/.*\($INSTANCE_NAME_PREFIX[0-9a-fA-F]*\).*/\1/g"`
```

I commented that block and ran the script again, this time it did not hang; thus completing its run.

I attempted to run `sudo virsh list --all` on my CloudLive VM and it just hands until I break out of it.

Why is `sudo virsh` hanging?

Your help is appreciated.

---

**Note 1:** The `virsh` command responds without `sudo`.

**Note 2:** Not sure it matters, but I'm running my Virtual Machines in VMWare Fusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure there are no running instances of `dmidecode`.

```
killall -9 dmidecode
```

Comment: Doesn't look like such a process is running.  I'm getting `dmidecode: no process found`

Comment: This resolution is as close as I'm going to get - thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

`killall dmidecode` worked for me.

I'm a bit surprised as I'm running on 12.04 which is using `libvirt 0.9.8` and from https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=796451 it looks like a fix went in to `0.9.6-5`.

Comment: Strange indeed - I'm still getting `dmidecode: no process found` on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

kill `dmidecode` works for me and continue to Django installation

use another shell or ssh

```
killall -9  dmidecode
```

for root user

or

```
sudo killall -9 dmidecode
```

for non root user